# getElementById with variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to use a variable with getElementById, but it just returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

My code looks about that

```
document.getElementsByClassName("right").onclick = function() {
    score++;
    score2++;

    document.getElementsByClassName("right").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementsByClassName("wrong").style.color = "red";

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display = "inline";
    }, 1500);
};
```

It´s a quiz and what it should do is, that, when a right answer (with the class right) is clicked it should add 1 to the score and one to score2 (score -1) and than after 1.5sec in which the right and wrong answers are highlighted using green and red the next answer should appear. For example after question 2 the score is 3 and the code should change the display (form css) from none (invisible) to inline (visible) and the answered question should disappear. For example after question 2 score2=2 and the code

```
document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display="none";
```

should make the question 2, which is in a div with the id question2 like all the others, invisible.

---EDIT---
The entire code:

```
var score = 0
var score2 =-1
document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
score++;
score2++;
console.log("Score:");
console.log(score);
console.log("Score2:");
console.log(score2);
document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display="block";
};

document.getElementsByClassName("right").onclick = function(){
score++;
score2++;
console.log("Score:");
console.log(score);
console.log("Score2:");
console.log(score2);
document.getElementsByClassName("right").style.color="green";
document.getElementsByClassName("wrong").style.color="red";
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display="inline";
},1500);
};
```

---EDIT---
The html code:
NOTE: There are some question divs w/o content, these are for up coming questions. In my js I use the second id of every div (like question8 not questionEight).

```
<div id="startScreen" id="question0">
    <h1>
        WELCOME TO THE 100 QUESTION GAME!
    </h1>

    <h2 id="go" style="color:pink">
        Lets GO!
    </h2>
    <p>
        by strawberry studios
    </p>

</div>
<div id="questionOne" id="question1" style="display:none;">
    <h1>
        Von wo aus kann man nur nach S&uuml;den gehen?
    </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerOne" class="right">Nordpol</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionOneAnswerTwo">S&uuml;dpol</a> <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerThree">&Auml;quator</a> <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerFour">Bayern</a> <br>
</div>

<div id="questionTwo" id="question2" style="display:none;">
    <h1>
        Was ist am teuersten?
    </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionTwoAnswerOne">Diamant</a> <br>
    <a id="quoestionTwonswerTwo">Platin</a> <br>
    <a id="questionTwoAnswerThree">Gold</a> <br>
    <a id="questionTwoAnswerFour" class="right">Osmium</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
</div>

<div id="questionThree" id="question3" style="display:none;">
    <h1>
        Wof&uuml;r steht HTML?
    </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerOne">Hyper Text Multiple Language</a> <br>
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerTwo">Hyper Text Markup Language</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerThree" class="right">Hydrotecinmultiliquid</a> <br>
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerFour">Hype The Mother (a)lLong<a/> <br>
</div>

<div id="questionFour" id="question4" style="display:none;">
    <h1>
        Welche Farbe h&auml;tte Cola ohne Farbstoffe?
    </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionFourAnswerOne">Gelb</a> <br>
    <a id="questionFouranswerTwo">Erdbraun</a> <br>
    <a id="questionFourAnswerThree" class="right">Grün</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionFourAnswerFour">Türkis<a/> <br>
</div>

<div id="questionFive" id="question5 "tyle="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="questionSix" id="question6" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="questionSeven" id="question7" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="questionEight" id="question8" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="questionNine" id="question9" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="questionTen" id="question10" style="display:none;">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try something like this (add jquery to your project)

```
$(".right").click(function() {
score++;
score2++;

var QuestionIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("right").indexOf(this);

document.getElementsByClassName("right")[QuestionIndex].style.color = "green";
document.getElementsByClassName("wrong")[QuestionIndex].style.color = "red";

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display = "inline";
}, 1500);
});
```

Comment: good idea, but I´ll try to use score as the questionIndex, in the first line of your code I already need getElementsByClassName and by then the questionIndex isn´t defined yet and the score will always raise by one too and is also one in the beginning (cos the go button also adds one, so the actual score that the player reached is score2).

Comment: the QuestionIndex will just get the position in the array of the item that was clicked to ensure that the correct "wrong" item is also selected and styled accordingly. will the score variable always reference the correct location in the arrays?

Comment: i think so cos it moves up one after every question

Comment: -1 `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements, you can't bind a click event to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("right")
```

Returns an Array. There can be more than one Element with the same className, so you have to say which one:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0].style.color="red";
```

would be correct if the element exists.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer corrected*: The problem was, apparently - before you put more code afterwards - that `score` and `score2` had not been initialized (so this answer doesn't stand any more for the current problem)
As simple example of what happens when you don't initialize a variable in Javascript can be here: http://jsfiddle.net/3L8qV/

Comment: I initialized both score and score -1 using `var score = 0
var score2 =-1` I only posted the part of code that makes problems.

Comment: If you put an `alert(score2)` before `document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display="none";` (and the same for the following instruction), what values does it show?

Comment: both values show 0 and -1 in the beginning and 1 and 0 after the go button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you're using two **id** for a `div` - I'm not saying that *you can't have two id's in a div*, because I'm not sure this general statement is true. For instance, if you have this div:

```
<div id="questionThree" id="question3" style="display:none;">
```

This script is not working:

```
alert(getElementById('question3'));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aY26X/3/

Comment: I already changed that. see https://floobits.com/BenBals/quiz.sublime-project#buf-quiz.sublime-project for my new code and vist http://100questiongame.tk to test the code. the right answers are Nordpol, Osmium, Hyper Text Markup Language and grün. In case you don´t speek german